# "Cheap mother" idiom

Tags: idioms

In this passage:

> Got a feature request? Found a bug? Think our mother is cheap? We'd love to hear from you!

([source](https://www.beeminder.com/contact))

What do they mean by "Think our mother is cheap?" there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a wry way of expressing that they welcome all feedback, including criticism.

If there is any idiom to be revealed, it is the general *[your mother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_insult)* ***_*__*_***, for instance:

- Your mother is so poor, she put a milkshake on layaway.
- Your mother is so fat, when she sits around the house, she sits *around the house*.

From the link:

> A maternal insult (also referred to as a yo momma joke) is a reference
>   to a person's mother through the use of phrases such as "your mother"
>   or other regional variants, frequently used to insult the target by
>   way of their mother.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_insult) Used as an insult, "your mother..." preys on
>   widespread sentiments of filial piety, making the insult particularly
>   and globally offensive.

---

### Edit:

As Dave says in comment,

> The other idiom is "___is cheap", referring to them being an inexpensive prostitute.

Comment: @Robusto word to your mother.

Comment: The other idiom is "___is cheap", referring to them being an inexpensive prostitute.

Answer (score -2):

The expression apparently derives from "Cheap mother*", an expletive in common usage, the expansion best left unstated.

Comment: This expression does not come from that. see @cornbreadninja 's answer.

Comment: Read the phrases of both answers out in your mind.